# Actualizar consulta en la misma página sin recargarla

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

Al rellenar el formulario de la misma página y darle al botón de "cambiar estado" , llamó  a ajax para que realice la actualización del estado, pero quiero que se actualice también en la página, es decir el estado de la tabla de la consulta que he cambiado.

Para ello mando también en el formulario la información que necesito para realizar la consulta, pero al recargarse la misma página, sale que no están definidas las variables enviadas en el post,cuando si que las estoy mandando.

La actualización del estado si que la realiza correctamente, pero tengo que recargar la página otra vez para ver la tabla actualizada.

La pregunta es , ¿hay alguna forma de actualizar el estado de la tabla sin actualizar completamente la página ? o ¿cómo arreglar está solución que he implementado sin que de error por variables no definidas?

P.d : ¿Se podría enviar el estado por json desde javascript a php y que este actualizará la consulta?

Gracias por la ayuda , me gustaría más cualquier solución que no pase por recargar la página.

```js
$(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Actualizar Estado.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                window.location.replace("Administrar Pedidos.php");
              
            }
          });

        });

      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
 
if($subs_idreserva==null && $subs_tipo=='próximos' ){
    
    $consulta= "Update tfg.pedidos  SET estado='Realizando' WHERE estado is null and idpedido=(SELECT id FROM tfg.reservas WHERE fecha='$fechahoy' and hora<'$horamas' and hora>'$horamenos');";
    
    $consulta= "SELECT * FROM tfg.pedidos WHERE idpedido=(SELECT id FROM tfg.reservas WHERE fecha='$fechahoy' and hora<'$horamas' and hora>'$horamenos');";

$resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta ) or die ( "Error en la Realización de la Búsqueda");


echo "<table borde='2'>";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th>Idpedido</th>";
 echo "<th>Pedido</th>";
 echo "<th>Estado</th>";
 echo "</tr>";
 // Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
 while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $columna['idpedido'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['pedido'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['estado']. "</td>"; 
  echo "</tr>";
 } 
 echo "</table>"; // Fin de la tabla
    mysqli_close( $conexion );
}

?>


<form action="Administrar Pedidos.php">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
                            <div style="padding-left:80px;">
                            <input type="text" name="idreserva" class="form-control" placeholder="  ¿Id de Reserva?" >
                        </div>
                           <div style="padding-left:80px"> 
                        <select  name="estado" class="form-control" >
                                <option value="nada" >¿Estado del Pedido?</option>
                                <option value="Completado">Completado</option>
                                <option value="Anulado">Anulado</option>
                                <option value="Realizando">Realizando</option>
                            </select>
                        <p></p>
                               <input type="text" name="pedidos" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $subs_idreserva ; ?>" >
                               <input type="text" name="tipo" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $subs_tipo ; ?>" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div style="padding-left:140px" >
                            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3"><span></span> Cambiar Estado</button>
                                <p></p>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que te aparece de 'variables no definidas' puede ser porque los elemento que intentas obtener han sido generados por el AJAX, por lo que si intentas acceder a ellos con un elemento normal DOM, te lanzará este fallo porque estás intentando acceder a algo que aún no ha sido creado.

Para evitar esto, tienes varias opciones:

- Usar el método [live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/), que permite obtener elementos generados en un 'futuro' ( *swuccess* del AJAX).
- Realizar las acciones dentro del *success* del AJAX.

Si decides usar la segunda opción, te recomiendo que en el *success* llames a una función que realice las tareas, así tu código será más limpio y legible.

Comment: Al realizar la acción de Update que realiza la función del Ajax,quiero que envíe los values del form a la página que será carga en el success "Administrar Pedidos.php", está página no recibe los datos del form y por eso da error de undefined, ¿cómo puedo mandarlos?

Comment: Ah, de acuerdo, el problema que veo es que en tu PHP, en ningún momento estás recibiendo los datos mandados del AJAX, debes tener algo tipo: $var = $_POST['name'], donde 'name' es el nombre de la variable del input del formulario. Para saber como que se envía al PHP, mira el contenido de $('form').serialize() con un console.log(), y recoge esos datos en el PHP. Espero que te ayude.